# Degrees of comparison

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

> The Nile is one of the longest rivers in the world.
>
> The Nile is longer than any other river/rivers in the world.

Should the noun **river** in the second sentence be plural or singular?

Comment: It should be "any other river" in the second sentence.

Comment: You have tagged this question "grammaticality-in-context" but you have not given us any context in which to judge.  Both sentences are correct in their own context.

Comment: the set of 'longest rivers' has only one member

Comment: @JonMark Perry: A certain man says and does some of *the stupidest things* and is pilloried for them by satirists on TV.  There are multiple items in that class.  It consists of items which share the characteristic of being far more stupid than other things.

Comment: @TRomano; however there is only one longest river in the world

Comment: @JonMark Perry. You misunderstand.  Natural language is not math. The set of longest rivers can contain multiple members. *Some of the tallest buildings in the world are in New York*.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Should I add this: Nagoya is one of the largest cities in Japan.

Answer (score 1):

A) *The Nile is one of the longest rivers in the world*

Sentence A implies that the Nile is *not* the longest river in the world, but is one of them. We would think this to mean the Nile is the second, third, fourth, or fifth longest, but definitely not the first. Somewhere near the top. This is because the use of the pronoun-preposition pair '*one of*' means the noun is part of a whole, or a group, not the pinnacle itself.

Even though you have used the superlative ending *'-est'* (which would normally mean the most of something) you have shown that the Nile is merely one example of the longest rivers, and not the longest river itself.

B) *The Nile is longer than any other rivers in the world*

Correction: *The Nile is longer than any other river in the world.* ('any' requires the noun to be singular, hence 'river' and not 'rivers'.)

Sentence B implies that the Nile is the longest river. Even though you've used the comparative ending *'-er'* (which would normally **not** mean the most of something), you have also stated that the Nile is comparatively long*er* than every single other river.

This would be like me saying, "I have mo*re* money than any other person."
I didn't say I was the rich*est* (the person with the most money), but I implied it by claiming that there was no one with more money than me.

Answer (score 0):

OP's context is slightly unusual, in that there's always been controversy regarding whether the actual "longest river in the world" is the Nile or the Amazon. Usually, ***one of*** the longest would strongly imply *not* being the longest of all (since we wouldn't normally include ***one of*** if it were the actual longest), but in this exact context it could well be a simple "hedge" to avoid accusations of inaccuracy.

---

Regarding OP's specific question, I'm sure there are pedants who think ***than any other X*** should always specify ***X*** in the singular (as opposed to ***than all other Xs***, say). But in reality, as pointed out by [this Pearson/Longman](http://www.pearsonlongman.com/ae/azar/grammar_ex/message_board/archive/articles/00029.htm) addressing the usage *than any other boy[s] in the class* is that...

> ***Both sentences are grammatically correct***.
>   *The question here is whether or not to use a singular noun or a plural noun in this comparison.*
>
> ***The choice is stylistic:*** does the writer want to compare his subject to **one** other (nonspecific) boy in the class, or to **all** of the boys in the class?

---

But I should just say I'd almost certainly use singular in OP's *exact* context. Partly because - as per my initial paragraph - there's only really one other river that's bound to be included in *any* set of "world's longest rivers". But also partly because in practice people *usually* use the singular form anyway, even if they haven't given any thought whatsoever to the potential nuance above.

---

It may be worth noting that Google Books has just 5 instances of [*than any other **rivers***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22than%20any%20other%20rivers%22) (as opposed to over 10,000 instances of [*than any other **river***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22than%20any%20other%20rivers%22#tbm=bks&q=%22than%20any%20other%20river%22)). But that's probably influenced by the points I've made here - the "preference" is far weaker with, say, [*than any other **option***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22than%20any%20other%20option%22) (3920 hits), where plural [*than any other **options***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22than%20any%20other%20options%22) gets an estimated 1480 hits. When a usage occurs *that* often, it simply makes no sense to say it's "wrong".

Answer (score 0):

Very very few native speakers would say this:

> Tommy is better at basketball than **any other boys** in class.

And yet the following sentence, in my estimation, would stand a much greater chance of being spoken:

> This is better than **any other options** we have.

I suspect the reason for this has something to do with the concreteness and discreteness (or the lack thereof) of what is being compared.  If the comparands are not concrete and discrete but somewhat amorphous and abstract, they coalesce into a mental blob more readily.

An editor would probably change OP's sentence to:

> The Nile is longer than **any other river** in the world.

It wouldn't be an act of editorial pedantry; that's how most native speakers would say it.